# Fix bootstrap menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some issues with bootstrap menu in some screens where it is not centered like in the others screens as you can see [here](http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fisioterapeutacamila.com%2Fmy-bootstrap)

I have removed **navbar-right** but it did not work. And I don´t have any special css alteration. Just some font size and colors.

```
<nav class="navbar">
<div class="container-fluid social-nav">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img alt="Facebook" src="images/soc-icon4.png"></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img alt="Instagram" src="images/soc-icon3.png"></a>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid menu-nav">
    <div class="navbar-header logo">
      <a href="index.html"><img alt="Dra Camila" src="images/logo.png"></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="myactive"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li><hr>
      <li><a href="sobre.html">About</a></li><hr>
      <li><a href="serviços.html">Services</a></li><hr>
      <li><a href="tratamentos.html">Treatments</a></li><hr>
      <li><a href="contato.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Any suggestion to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of padding in `menu-nav` and you're all set:

```
.menu-nav {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    /* padding: 10px 150px 10px 150px; */
}
```

For other problems on iPad view, assign width to your floated items and change menu:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-right {
    /* float: right!important; */
    /* margin-right: -15px; */
}
```

Comment: good but **iPad portrait · width: 768px** still gets the same =(

Comment: It's not the same, you have other issues in your css.

Comment: It was really a floating issue. I fixed it with **.logo, .nav, .nav li { text-align: center !important; float: none !important; }** . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
     <div class="container-fluid">          
         <!-- Logo -->
         <div class="navbar-header">
             <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             </button>
             <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">COLLAPSE NAVBAR</a>
         </div>

         <!-- Menu Items -->
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                 <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
             </ul>  
         </div>

     </div>
 </nav>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 950px) {
.navbar-header {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

}